# Trying to add intro on big amount of videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, embedding

first time asking a question here so sorry if im not doing it right.

so i've got lots of videos on different folders. im trying to add an intro and a watermark on them all
watermark should be added to the video and then the intro should be added after.
i tried ffmpeg on a video it worked but the video is so damn slow like x.25 or something

im trying to write a batch script that does the whole thing on all folders.
some of them are like :
folder/video.mp4
folder/subfolder/subfolder/video.mp4

i don't know how to deal with those and im talking like 6k videos.

again sorry if im not doing it right.
i tried something like this : in batch.

```
(for %%i in (*.mp4) do @echo file '%%i') > ./list.txt
ffmpeg -f concat -i ./list.txt -c copy ./output.mp4
PAUSE
```

Comment: Do you need help with batch or ffmpeg? Adding a watermark will require you to re-encode everything, so it may be slow. There are a few things you can do to speed it up (use a faster preset and stream copy the audio for example), but if speed is important consider not adding a watermark. Then you can potentially concatenate the intro and not re-encode the main content.

Comment: im doing it through ffmpeg but im using batch to automate it all.
since im dealing with 6k videos in different folders